# How to implement ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to implement ajax in laravel framework, where I am trying to check for the availability for the username, I was able to implement the same via core php but not able to get through laravel 4.

Answer (score 1):

1)  You have to define a method in your controller (i.e UserController)

```
public function postEmail()
{
    $userCount = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->count();
    if ($userCount == 0) 
    {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

2) In your registration form you have to do jQuery validation like this to make a remote call on Controller method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#registration-form').validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/user/email'
                    }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    remote: "The email has already been taken!"
                }
            },           
            success: function(date) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is url: '/user/email'

Comment: this is url to access/ make a request the method for that first you have to define a route in routes.php         Route::post('user/email', array(
    'as'=> 'userCheck',
    'uses'=>'UsersController@postEmail'
    ));